# Where can I find the graduate school college scorecard data

Tags: collegescorecard

I want to know the data and information about graduate schools. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 2):

There is none at this time, though I've read that the Dept of Education may be making effort to add that information in future versions of the College Scorecard itself.

Currently, you *can* get grad school data from College Navigator (http://nces.ed.gov/collegenavigator/) and IPEDS DataCenter (http://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/)

Comment: where can one find a master list of UnitIDs? 5 minutes searching on ipeds datacenter site, found nothing.

Comment: There isn't any per se. I had to create my own, but it's part of a private OpenRefine project. You can create one in datacenter, by selecting "EZ Group" for the institutions and no additional variables. What you'll get is a list of school name and id, and a button/link to download that. Keep in mind that you're selecting from 7,000+ institutions in the database, so indicate study levels, control (public, private), etc., when refining the list of institutions.

Comment: Caveat: there is still isn't a lot of grad school data in NCES and DataCenter

Comment: ...why not just share the own you created?

Comment: Because I didn't create what you need. I have a private client file I can't share, as I indicated above, and it has 163 columns, not 2 -- as well, it's not grad-specific. It's really not that hard to generate, once you understand the Datacenter  interface. That takes a bit of playing around with, the but their Web server does occasionally generate Java (not JavaScript) errors and can get very frustrating.